# Having problems sending email from MailR for an Amazon email?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, sendmailr

I've used MailR to automate and send mass emails easily and straightforward with my personal Gmail. However, using my Amazon email as been a problem and hasn't worked? My Amazon email is through outlook, but I've tried the host for outlook and hasn't worked.. Any help would be great, so I can figure this out!!

```
      sender <- "jsmith@amazon.com"
      receipient <- "jsmith@gmail.com"

     send.mail(from = sender,
     to = receipient,
     subject = "subject",
     body = "msg", 
     authenticate = TRUE,
     smtp = list(host.name = "smtp.office365.com", port = 587,
        user.name = "jsmith@amazon.com", passwd = "password", tls = 
     TRUE))`


Caused by: com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to 
host, port: smtp.office365.com, 587; timeout 60000;
nested exception is:
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2053)
at   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:386)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:245)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:194)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java``:124)
at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1400)
... 6 more
```

Comment: looks more like the port is not open to send emails through your amazon account and is timing out.

Comment: @Not_Dave do you know how I should go about this?

Comment: if its your corporate account talk to your IT management. On the other note I just realized that you are using your amazon email. You should be using amazon's smtp and port. [Here is the link for it ](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/smtp-connect.html)